# Access values returned by select and return SQL statements

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a problem with SQL Server in C# and the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestingReturn]
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SELECT -2 AS Id
   RETURN -1
END
```

How can I access return value? C# generated code allows only to access value returned from select:

```
model.TestingReturn_Result foo = model.TestingReturn();

if (foo != null)
{
    int bar = Convert.ToInt32(foo.FirstOrDefault().Id); // -2
}
```

Thank you, best regards,

Comment: Are you **really** using `Linq-to-SQL` (ORM with a `.dbml` model file), or is this really more **Entity Framework** that is being used? (with an `.edmx` model file, or a code-first approach without a visual model)

Comment: @marc_s how would it matter? AFAIK neither support this scenario...

Comment: I'm using framework with .edmx model

Comment: in that case @marc_s is correct - you shouldn't refer to it as linq-to-sql; that is a **largely unrelated technology** (other than it serves similar aims)

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: this answer applies to [linq-to-sql](/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql) (the original question tags); I do not know whether [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) supports this scenario directly.

---

In linq-to-sql, if you want to access both `select` and `return` values, you'll need to drop to ADO.NET and add a parameter with direction `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`, and execute the command as a data-reader (`ExecuteReader`). Then *after consuming* all the data from the data-reader, you can access the `.Value` of the parameter you added.